# Show bit strings with count(1s) = count(0s) isn't regular

Tags: regex, algorithm, regular-language, automata, proof

Let L be the language consisting of strings over alphabet {0,1} that contain an equal number of 1s and 0s.

For example:

```
000111
10010011
10
1010101010
```

How can you show that L isn't a regular language?

Comment: You probably mean `count`, not `sum`.

Comment: @Kobi is there some esoteric language theory point you're trying to make?  Otherwise the sum of "n" 1s is the same as the count of "n" 1s.

Comment: Does this help: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/g51mal/notes-3x.pdf ?

Comment: @Alnitak - but not the zeros. I agree it's pedantic though.

Comment: @Kobi ah yes - good point about the zeros :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the exact same argument that is used to show that {0^n 1^n: n > 0} is not regular, since you are free to choose the string that will contradict the pumping lemma.

Assume L is regular. So it must satisfy the pumping lemma for some integer n (the pumping length). Take the string `S=0^n 1^n`, which belongs to L. According to the lemma, it can be split as `S=xyz` with `|xy| <= n`, `|y|>0`, and `x y^i z` belonging to L, for all `i>=0`. Observe that `y` must consist of zeros only. Now pump `y`, and you are only adding zeros to the string, which no longer belongs to L. So you have a contradiction. So L is not regular.

Comment: @Kobi: I think the string I chose will do for the proof.

Comment: According to Wikipedia and rparree's link, it should be |xy| <= n. And because of this, xy can only cover the first half of S=0^n 1^n at most, which means y can only contain zeros.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a formal proof, but the intuition is that you cannot construct a DFA to recognize this language (consider that it would require an unobounded number of states to keep track of strings of the form `111...111000...000` or similar).

Comment: This is not the language {0^n 1^n: n > 0}, the digits may be in any order.  How can you use the pumping lemma to show the language described in the Q is non-regular?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: But that is a sub-language of the language you're interested in.

Comment: And it is also a sublanguage of `0*1*`, and that is regular.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: That's a good point.  In that case, I'll restrict my answer to the intuitive argument!

Comment: Andrew: If your language L was regular, then intersection L and 0*1* would be regular (since regular languages are closed under intersection). But the intersection is 0^n 1^n, which is known to be irregular.

Answer (score 0):

The formal proof can be given using the pumping lemma for regular languages as follows:

Suppose the language is regular. So it must satisfy the pumping lemma for a const integer p. Let `s` be any string with equal number of 0s and 1s. Then s can be divided into 3 parts x,y,z such that `|xy|<=p`, `|y|>0`, then `x(y^i)z`, where `i>=0`should also belong to L.

Let me divide the string as follows:

- `y` is a part of string which has unequal number of 0s and 1s.
- `x` could be the substring of `s` before `y`.
- `z` could be the part after `y`.

Now, if i "pump down" the string by taking `i = 0`, then the remaining string would be only `xz` which will definitely have unequal number of 0s and 1s which does not belong to the language L.

Thus we have reached a contradiction as we earlier assumed L to be regular.

Therefore, it is not regular.

If it was a little hard understanding the above part, consider an example.
Let p be an integer 5. Let `0+1000+11101` be a string in L. (+ indicates concatenation)
Let me take x to be "`0`", y be `"1000"`, z be the remaining part `11101`.
Then if we perform `x(y^i)z` with `i=0`, the remaining string would be `011101` which is not a part of L. Thus irregular.

Note: the example was just a sample to make you understand the logic. One cannot decide the value of p randomly.